# Which talks/videos appealed to you as a developer?

Tags: video, computer-science

Which talks/videos appealed to you as a developer?

I really like this talk by Clay Shirky:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe1TZaElTAs
And, Startup School talk by David:
http://www.omnisio.com/startupschool08/david-heinemeier-hansson-at-startup-school-08

Which ones you recommend? please provide links and a short description if possible.

Edit: i know there's a thread [What are great programming-related online talks / videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282534/what-are-great-programming-related-online-talks-videos).. but i'm looking for more general, not specifically programming focused talks/videos.

Comment: Second one was the best one ive seen in a lot of time KUDOS and thanks for posting your question =)

Answer (score 2):

Lawrence Lessig used to give an excellent talk on intellectual property in software development and open source in particular. Though not directly applicable to everyday development skills, I found it fascinating. I saw it at the OOPSLA conference in 2003, but I am sure he gave a similar talk in many other venues, maybe it had been recorded. He also wrote a great book, called " Code: And Other Laws of Cyberspace".

Answer (score 2):

The Google [Videos from the Googleplex](http://video.google.com/googleplex.html) are generally fascinating - there are so many excellent choices, I don't want to single any out.

The Tech Talks are great for a variety of different technologies. Topics also include "Current Affairs, Science, Engineering, Humanities, Business, Law, Entertainment, Medicine, and the Arts"!

Plus, they also have the Authors@Google section which includes preeminent speakers "sharing their thoughts" on various things.

Answer (score 1):

[14 rules for website performance](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/1040890/3880720).

Answer (score 0):

I liked quite a few of the TED talks, e.g. the one on OLPC.

Answer (score 0):

"How to grow your site from 1 to 1 million users". Great talk from Kevin Rose at FOWA 2009

http://vimeo.com/6905398